# given two vertices in an undirected graph find if there are two vertex disjoint paths connecting them

Tags: graphs

Why does the following procedure not work?

Let given vertices be $(u,v)$

1. Run a dfs from any vertex.
   Compute : $low[u]$ for all vertices in the graph
   $low[u] = min(disc[u], disc[w]) $
   where w is an ancestor of u and there is a back edge from 
   some descendant of u to w.
2. In the tree formed by dfs, find the $lca(u,v)$ of given nodes.
3. If $lca$ is $u$ or $v$:

   - (Say $lca = u  $ wlog)  if $low[v] <= disc[lca]$  then yes else no.
4. If $lca$ is not any of the given nodes:

   - if $low[u]<disc[lca]$ and $low[v]<disc[lca]$   then yes else no.

Here one of the path is $u->lca->v$ and other is using the back edge.
Let $low[u]=low[p]$ where $p$ is a descendent of $u$
and $low[v]=low[q]$ where $q$ is a descendent of $v$.
$p$ to $low[p]$ is a back edge and so is $q$ to $low[q]$.

$u->p->low[p]->low[q]->q->v$ is the other path

Please provide with an example to show why does this not work?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Anyway, why do you believe this doesn't work?  What have you tried?  Have you tried writing a program to generate a million random trees, and running your procedure on this and comparing its output to that of a known-good algorithm to see if you can find any counterexamples?  P.S. In LaTeX you can use `\le` for $\le$ and `\to` for $\to$; that will look better than $<=$ and $->$.